# Ошибка преобразования типов VS2010 (2013) C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, типы-данных, double, преобразование-типов

Столкнулся с ошибкой преобразования компилятора С++ величин из типа `uint64_t` в тип `double`. Ошибка иногда проявляется при округлении младшего бита мантиссы, если старший бит исходной величины = "1".

**Примеры**:

```
Source: 0x8CC12811A56A3BB1
C++   : 1.0142431892069827E+019, back: 8CC12811A56A4000, delta = 1103
Waited: 1.0142431892069825E+019, back: 8CC12811A56A3800, delta = 945

Source: 0x8407413F03C2CB1D
C++   : 9.5136444767453061E+018, back: 8407413F03C2D000, delta = 1251
Waited: 9.5136444767453041E+018, back: 8407413F03C2C800, delta = 797

Source: 0xC961281B6505140F
C++   : 1.4510923572488507E+019, back: C961281B65051000, delta = 1039
Waited: 1.4510923572488509E+019, back: C961281B65051800, delta = 1009

Source: 0xB5B8374FFA1C74DB
C++   : 1.3094276733217829E+019, back: B5B8374FFA1C7000, delta = 1243
Waited: 1.3094276733217831E+019, back: B5B8374FFA1C7800, delta = 805

Source: 0xDC0EF98B2E2C2B98<br>
C++   : 1.5856885714188513E+019, back: DC0EF98B2E2C3000, delta = 1128
Waited: 1.5856885714188511E+019, back: DC0EF98B2E2C2800, delta = 920
```

`back`:  означает обратное преобразование (из `double` в `uint64_t`)
`delta`: означает разницу результата и оригинала.
C# или MinGW работают адекватно.

Answer (score 1):

На сегодняшний день не существует ни одного компилятора (для языка Си), который умел бы правильно переводить числа из десятичной записи в формат с плавающей точкой, то же касается и конвертирования типов данных из одного в другой. Ближе всех к правильной работе с плавающими числами компилятор Intel, но и против него у меня есть тесты. Число ошибок в компиляторах Microsoft настолько огромно, что неправильным конвертированием удивить трудно, там полно и другой ерунды.

Немного с другого ракурса я показал эту проблему с плавающими числами [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5Y4-4SKaSA) (видео).

Если Вы задаёте вопрос с целью найти решение данной проблемы, то одно здесь одно - выполнять конвертирование самостоятельно. Для типа в 64 бита это сделать очень просто, если знать формат чисел с плавающей точкой, описанный в стандарте IEEE-754. Гораздо сложнее решить задачу общего вида.

Ну и есть такой момент ещё: возможно, Вы что-то неправильно делаете. Чаще всего ошибки программистов в том, что они что-то не понимают. Я не видел Вашего кода, поэтому не могу говорить наверняка.

Comment: C# или MinGW работают адекватно.

Comment: Не вижу причин, считать, что эта задача не разрешима.
По стандарту IEEE-754 округление производится либо к ближайщему целому, либо в меньшую сторону.
Под вопросом остается только случай, когда остаток равен половине единички (0,100000).
В случае с компилятором C++ из VS мы видим просто ошибку. И только в случае преобразования uint64_t в double.
int64_t в double конвертируется корректно.
Вообще-то это не вопрос, а сообщение.

Comment: Код для первого приведенного числа:
 uint64_t uv = 0x8CC12811A56A3BB1;
 double dv = (double)uv;
 uint64_t back_un = (uint64_t)dv;

Comment: @Саша, а я и не говорю, что задача неразрешима. Я, например, знаю формат и умею решать данную задачу. Что касается MinGW, то и против него у меня есть тесты (ссылку давал в ответе, там под видео архив) с десятичными числами, на которых он выдаст неправильный ответ. И кстати, по Стандарту округление производится не совсем так, как Вы написали. В случае, когда два ближайших целых (мы как бы ровно посередине) округление идёт к тому, у которого будет младший значащий ноль в мантиссе (к чётной мантиссе). И вообще там 4 режима округления на самом деле.

Comment: Артем! Вы невнимательны. Это раз. Во вторых, Конкретно для преобразования  uint64_t в double компилятор С++ глючит. Он именно неправильно округляет.

Comment: @Саша, невнимательны на самом деле Вы, потому что я объяснил, что ошибками компилятора здесь никого не удивишь. На данный момент нет даже ни одного компилятора с языка Си++, который целиком поддерживал бы стандарт без ошибок. А неправильным округлением вообще можно удивить только начинающего программиста. Не знаю, чего ещё вы хотите. Адекватного вопроса с Вашей стороны я не вижу. Поделиться же ошибкой компилятора можно с разработчиками Microsoft, и то они вам сообщат в ответ, что либо их эта ошибка не интересует, либо что они о ней знают и она исправлена, например в VS-2015 (и то вряд ли).

Comment: Артем! Чтобы без ля-ля - приведите еще  пример ошибки преобразования форматов с конкретными примерами. Иначе как-то голословно у вас все.

Comment: Примеры ошибок в преобразовании из десятичного формата в плавающий есть в моём видео (ссылка была дана), примеры конвертирования из целочисленного формата в дробный и обратно могут быть найдены Вами самостоятельно обычным перебором (подскажу, что нужно искать примеры, в которых при округлении число находится почти ровно по центру между двумя возможными значениями - верхним и нижним). Я не уверен, что буду продолжать эту дискуссию, свою позицию я обозначил, она может не совпадать с общепринятой, и тем мне в данный момент лучше.

Comment: Артем. У меня нет желания смотреть ваше видео. Вы можете в тексте привести пример? Если не можете - лучше помолчите

Comment: Нет желания разбираться, не начинайте разговор. По ссылке, что я дал, можно скачать архив. До свидания.

Comment: Не знаете примеров ошибок - не надо говорить, что ими пестрят компиляторы. Это просто клевета

Comment: [Вот часть примеров из моих многомегабайтных архивов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512292/%d0%a1%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81)

Comment: Вам так хочется, чтоб кто-то копался в ваших многомега... Несерьезно. Я здесь писал о ПРЕОБРАЗОВАНИИ ТИПОВ. Это не совсем то, о чем вы пишите. Если вы можете отличить эти понятия

Comment: Вам не надоело демонстрировать свою неспособность разбираться в своих же вопросах. Я дал ЧАСТЬ примеров из архивов, они умещаются на экран. Мне даже уже нашли компилятор, которых их проходит. А вам лишь бы написать чушь, не посмотрев ответ. Удачи с такими проблемами. Что касается преобразования типов - там та же проблема, один в один. Тесты можно построить вручную. Сами справитесь.

Answer (score -1):

Компиляторы С++ от Micrisoft MS2010 и MS2013 при преобразовании величин из **uint64_t** в **double** допускают ошибку округления в младшем бите. Я заметил это только для случаев исходных чисел, в которых старший бит равен '1'.