# Существует ли компилятор с языка C++, который корректно переводит десятичное число в формат IEEE-754?

Tags: c++, компиляция, float, double

По роду деятельности я был вынужден плотно работать с форматом IEEE-754, в процессе чего обнаружил, что ни один из известных мне компиляторов (VC++, Intel C++, CLang, GCC (именно MinGW)) не умеет конвертировать некоторые числа в десятичной записи (типа, 1.2345e67) в формат с плавающей точкой. Все компиляторы, что я проверял, падают на несложных тестах, когда неочевидным для компилятора является способ округления (вверх или вниз). Примеры таких тестов можно увидеть в [этом cpp файле](https://github.com/Zealint/fp_tests/blob/master/TestIEEE754Convertion.cpp) (код слишком длинный, чтобы постить сюда). Мой вопрос таков: знаете ли вы компилятор, который без ошибок пройдёт хотя бы эти простые тесты (**все** из этого файла)? Если таковой найдётся, я предоставлю более сложные тесты. Просто скомпилируйте и запустите программу, она выдаст на консоль, что пройдено, а что нет. Кто найдёт такой компилятор, прошу назвать его в ответе.

Может быть кто-то захочет проверить работу тестов на других языках, буду рад узнать результат, только вам сначала придётся написать похожую программу на основе данных тестов.

PS. Если же кому-то будет интересна причина падения, я объяснял её в одной из своих бесед (см. [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5Y4-4SKaSA))

**UPD**: [Тесты против СLang](https://github.com/Zealint/fp_tests/blob/master/TestIEEE754ConvertionHard.cpp) (GCC их проходит). Предложенные тесты соответствуют стандарту языка C++ (длина строки и лексемы не превышает 65535 символов). У меня ещё есть несколько десятков тестов против CLang, которые рушат компилятор напрочь. Все связаны с long double (например, подайте ему на вход минимальное денормализованное число, он упадёт). Должен, однако, признать, что для float и double CLang действительно проходит все мои тесты, но часто выдаёт предупреждения при компиляции там, где не должен. В любом случае, данный компилятор также не поддерживает формат IEEE-754 полностью.

**UPD2**: [Тесты](https://github.com/Zealint/fp_tests/blob/master/TestIEEE754ConvertionHard2.cpp), которые валят CLang и не работают в GCC (MinGW).

**UPD3**: Все тесты теперь на [GitHub](https://github.com/Zealint/fp_tests). Позже, когда у меня наступит ясность (или, быть может, кто-то найдёт у меня ошибки) по данному вопросу, я объединю всё в один файл для удобства.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38370/discussion-on-question-by-zealint------c-).

Comment: UPD2: `gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010` OK. (Начиная с -O2 (-Os?)  -Wall и без -fno-strict-aliasing куча warnings типа `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]`)  А что значит **падают на несложных тестах**? Прямо таки -- segmentation fault или zerodivide с core dump???

Comment: @avp, да, мы уже выяснили, что gcc старших версий научился решать данную задачу. Падают - это значит дают неправильный ответ (м. б. неверный оборот речи, согласен). А CLang падает в прямом смысле, но выдаёт какое-то диагностическое сообщение.

Comment: Я думаю, вы выяснили далеко не все. Ошибки в программах были, есть и всегда будут (в т.ч. в компайлерах). Правильно, это не когда программа *формально правильна*, а когда она *фактически (на заданном оборудовании) решает задачу*.

Comment: Нет, Вы не так поняли. То, что в компиляторах (во ВСЕХ) полно ошибок, я и так знаю, и у меня есть несколько сотен тестов, это подтверждающих. Здесь меня интересовал лишь вопрос конвертирования десятичных чисел в IEEE-754. Оказалось, что GCC скорее всего умеет это делать правильно (а тот, который у меня из MinGW - не умеет). Остальные компиляторы не умеют даже этого.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что они неправильно пакуют битики в 4(8) байтные области, причем делают это по  разному?

Comment: Нет, не хочу. Перевод числа в формат с плавающей точкой - это сложный алгоритм, который занимается паковкой "битиков" только на последнем этапе. Сначала эти "битики" нужно правильно вычислить. Я подробно рассказал об этой проблеме на видео, ссылка на который в вопросе. Не думаю, что имеет смысл обсуждать данный вопрос в комментариях.

Comment: @Zealint, я в чат перебрался.

Answer (score 5):

**Base**

Gcc 5.3.0, судя по всему прошёл:

```
$ gcc TestIEEE754Convertion.cpp 
TestIEEE754Convertion.cpp:80:3: warning: floating constant truncated to zero [-Woverflow]
   -2.470328229206232720882843964341106861825e-324,
   ^
TestIEEE754Convertion.cpp:19:3: warning: anonymous type with no linkage used to declare variable ‘<anonymous union> f32’ with linkage
 } f32;
   ^
TestIEEE754Convertion.cpp:25:3: warning: anonymous type with no linkage used to declare variable ‘<anonymous union> f64’ with linkage
 } f64;
   ^

$ ./a.out 


::: Single precision :::
Right on test 0
Right on test 1
Right on test 2
Right on test 3
Right on test 4
Right on test 5
Right on test 6
Right on test 7

::: Double precision :::
Right on test 0
Right on test 1
Right on test 2
Right on test 3
Right on test 4
Right on test 5
Right on test 6
Right on test 7
Right on test 8
Right on test 9
Right on test 10
Right on test 11
Right on test 12
Right on test 13
Right on test 14
Right on test 15
Right on test 16
Right on test 17
Right on test 18
Right on test 19
Right on test 20
Right on test 21
Right on test 22
Right on test 23
```

Gcc 4.8.5:

```
$ ./a.out 


::: Single precision :::
Right on test 0
Right on test 1
Right on test 2
Right on test 3
Right on test 4
Right on test 5
Right on test 6
Right on test 7

::: Double precision :::
Right on test 0
Right on test 1
Right on test 2
Right on test 3
Right on test 4
Right on test 5
Right on test 6
Right on test 7
Right on test 8
Right on test 9
Right on test 10
Error on test 11: 0x7fefffffffffffff != 0x7feffffffffffffe
Error on test 12: 0x7fefffffffffffff != 0x7feffffffffffffe
Right on test 13
Right on test 14
Right on test 15
Right on test 16
Right on test 17
Right on test 18
Right on test 19
Error on test 20: 0x8000000000000000 != 0x8000000000000001
Right on test 21
Right on test 22
Right on test 23
```

Gcc 4.9.3:

```
$ ./a.out 


::: Single precision :::
Right on test 0
Right on test 1
Right on test 2
Right on test 3
Right on test 4
Right on test 5
Right on test 6
Right on test 7

::: Double precision :::
Right on test 0
Right on test 1
Right on test 2
Right on test 3
Right on test 4
Right on test 5
Right on test 6
Right on test 7
Right on test 8
Right on test 9
Right on test 10
Right on test 11
Right on test 12
Right on test 13
Right on test 14
Right on test 15
Right on test 16
Right on test 17
Right on test 18
Right on test 19
Right on test 20
Right on test 21
Right on test 22
Right on test 23
```

**Hard 2**

Для UPD2 Gcc 5 тоже молодец:

```
$ gcc TestIEEE754ConvertionHard2.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
OK
```

Gcc 4.8.5 - ERROR, Gcc 4.9.3 - OK

**Hard 3**

```
$ g++-5 -O0 ./TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp 
./TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp:19:3: предупреждение: anonymous type with no linkage used to declare variable «<anonymous union> f32» with linkage
 } f32;
   ^
./TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp:25:3: предупреждение: anonymous type with no linkage used to declare variable «<anonymous union> f64» with linkage
 } f64;
   ^
$ ./a.out 

::: Double precision :::
Right on test 0
Right on test 1
Right on test 2
Right on test 3
Right on test 4
Right on test 5
Right on test 6
Right on test 7
Right on test 8
```

Судя по всему прошёл. Gcc 4.9 - аналогично. Gcc 4.8 сфейлил тесты 5, 7, 8

**Strict aliasing**

Кстати, я могу что-то путать, но разве такие преобразования:

```
#define TEST(HI, LO, F) f = F;  if (*(((unsigned short int*)&f)+4) != HI || *(unsigned long long*)&f != LO) { printf ("ERROR"); return 1; }
```

не нарушают правило strict-aliasing? Не, конечно `-Wstrict-aliasing -fstrict-aliasing` это место пропускает и код на рабочих компиляторах работает. Но как-то, малость, не по себе.

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам. Прошу проверить UPD2 в исходном вопросе. Если выдаст OK, значит GCC молодец, если выдаст ERROR, значит какой-то тест валится.

Comment: @Zealint, обновил

Comment: спасибо. А не пробовали набор тестов Hard3? Там ситуация ещё немного жёстче. Если и их пройдёт, значит, по-видимому, GCC5 как раз будет единственным компилятором, который умеет работать с форматом IEEE-754. Что касается strict-aliasing, здесь не тот случай, когда нужно бояться этого нарушения. Здесь всё прозрачно: я просто обращаюсь к отдельным словам 80-битного числа и ничего страшного с ними не делаю, только сравниваю. Правда, код little-endian-зависимый.

Comment: @Zealint: Ну, поскольку нарушение strict aliasing формально UB, компилятор имеет право хоть вообще выкинуть всю функцию. (Вы думаете, просто так ядро компилируют с `-O2`?)

Comment: @VladD, ну ядро собирают не плюсовым компилятором :) Там чууууточку попроще, по крайней мере оговорено про union более формально. Ну и именно strict-aliasing на `-O2` уже включается. А так у меня был печальный опыт сборки Emacs с `-O3` - он тупо сразу падал.

Comment: Да это всё понятно, но если бы я ставил целью написать некий универсальный тест на все-все случаи, написал бы, только здесь ЦЕЛЬ иная - протестировать внутренний конвертер десятичной записи в плавающую точку. Компилятор можно попросить закрыть глаза на грязные трюки, потому что данный тест проверяет ДРУГУЮ его особенность. То есть в данном случае ничего плохого мы не делаем. Если программа выдала OK, то всё хорошо, я ответ на вопрос получил. Буду ковыряться дальше.

Comment: @MonahTuk: Но тем же gcc, попробую предположить? Оптимизационное ядро, думаю, не так уж сильно зависит от фронтэнда.

Comment: @Zealint, компиляторы вы хотите пощупать разные, а они по разному могут отнестись к такому коду. Тогда дайте рекомендацию использовать -fno-strict-aliasing или собирать с -O0 (для верности). MSVC данный тип оптимизации не использует, там проще. Для clang опцию - я не знаю. Hard3

Comment: @Zealint обновил для Hard 3

Comment: Спасибо. Тут ниже уже подтвердили, что проходит. Не думаю, что нужно закрывать этот вопрос, хотя ответ я получил (GCC победил), потому что может быть найдутся ещё какие-то компиляторы или кто-то проверит другие языки. А может и найдёт ещё тесты, которых у меня нет. В любом случае, тема интересная.

Comment: Вы ещё оптимизацию добавьте.

Comment: @MonahTuk, clang (судя по их статьям про UB) явные касты указателей старается прощать и понимать, что происходит.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да тут, вроде, только GCC впереди планеты всей

Answer (score 2):

C# 6, судя по всему, прошёл. Адаптированный тест, MSVC 2015, выдаёт:

> ::: Single precision :::
>
> Right on test 0
>   Right on test 1
>   Right on test 2
>   Right on test 3
>   Right on test 4
>   Right on test 5
>   Right on test 6
>   Right on test 7
>
> ::: Double precision :::
>
> Right on test 0
>   Right on test 1
>   Right on test 2
>   Right on test 3
>   Right on test 4
>   Right on test 5
>   Right on test 6
>   Right on test 7
>   Right on test 8
>   Right on test 9
>   Right on test 10
>   Right on test 11
>   Right on test 12
>   Right on test 13
>   Right on test 14
>   Right on test 15
>   Right on test 16
>   Right on test 17
>   Right on test 18
>   Right on test 19
>   Right on test 20
>   Right on test 21
>   Right on test 22
>   Right on test 23
>
> ::: Double precision (TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp) :::
>
> Right on test 0
>   Right on test 1
>   Right on test 2
>   Right on test 3
>   Right on test 4
>   Right on test 5
>   Right on test 6
>   Right on test 7
>   Right on test 8

Адаптированный исходник:

```
class Program
{
    // Тестирование числа одинарной точности
    void test32(float a, uint right, int testNumber)
    {
        var floatBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
        var uintValue = BitConverter.ToUInt32(floatBytes, 0);
        if (uintValue != right)
            Console.WriteLine($"Error on test {testNumber}: {uintValue:x8} != {right:x8}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Right on test {testNumber}");
    }

    // Тестирование числа двойной точности
    void test64(double a, ulong right, int testNumber)
    {
        var ulongValue = (ulong)BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(a);
        if (ulongValue != right)
            Console.WriteLine($"Error on test {testNumber}: {ulongValue:x16} != {right:x16}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Right on test {testNumber}");
    }

    // Список чисел одинарной точности и правильных двоичных представлений этих чисел
    const int N32 = 8;

    float[] Test32 = new float[ N32 ]
    {
        21267649200209254194690314461188718593.0f,
        1.175494280757364291727882991035766513322e-38f,
        1.175494280757364291727882991035766513323e-38f,
        10749727.50000000000000000000000000000001f,
        10749728.50000000000000000000000000000001f,
        -1.175494420887210724209590083408724842314e-38f,
        -1.175494420887210724209590083408724842315e-38f,
        -340282336497324057985868971510891282432.1f
    };

    uint[] Right32 = new uint[ N32 ]
    {
        0x7d800001,
        0x007fffff,
        0x00800000,
        0x4b240720,
        0x4b240721,
        0x80800000,
        0x80800001,
        0xff7fffff
    };

    // Список чисел двойной точности и правильных двоичных представлений этих чисел
    const int N64 = 24;

    double[] Test64 = new double[ N64 ]
    {
        -2.470328229206232720882843964341106861825e-324,
        -2.470328229206232720882843964341106861826e-324,
        2.225073858507200641991763955462587799366e-308,
        2.225073858507200641991763955462587799367e-308,
        6755399441055826.499999999999999999999999,
        6755399441055826.500000000000000000000001,
        179769313486231560835325876058105298516207002341652166261661174625869553267292326574530099287946549246750631490335877017522087105926987962906277604735569213290190919152394180476217125334960946356387261286640198029037799514183602981511756283727771403830521483963923935633133642802139091669457927874464075218944.1,
        11417981541647677146990387413251858846007164927.9,
        11417981541647677146990387413251858846007164928.0,
        11417981541647677146990387413251858846007164928.1,
        11417981541647677780815687527366559594358767616.0,
        179769313486231560835325876058105298516207002341652166261661174625869553267292326574530099287946549246750631490335877017522087105926987962906277604735569213290190919152394180476217125334960946356387261286640198029037799514183602981511756283727771403830521483963923935633133642802139091669457927874464075218943.9,
        179769313486231560835325876058105298516207002341652166261661174625869553267292326574530099287946549246750631490335877017522087105926987962906277604735569213290190919152394180476217125334960946356387261286640198029037799514183602981511756283727771403830521483963923935633133642802139091669457927874464075218944.0,
        179769313486231560835325876058105298516207002341652166261661174625869553267292326574530099287946549246750631490335877017522087105926987962906277604735569213290190919152394180476217125334960946356387261286640198029037799514183602981511756283727771403830521483963923935633133642802139091669457927874464075218944.1,
        9214843084008499.0,
        0.500000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875,
        30078505129381147446200.0,
        3.518437208883201171875e13,
        8.10109172351e-10,
        9007199254740991.4999999999999999999999999999999995,
        -2.4703282292062327208828439643411068618252990130716238221279284125033775363510437593264991818081799618989828234772285886546332835517796989819938739800539093906315035659515570226392290858392449105184435931802849936536152500319370457678249219365623669863658480757001585769269903706311928279558551332927834338409351978015531246597263579574622766465272827220056374006485499977096599470454020828166226237857393450736339007967761930577506740176324673600968951340535537458516661134223766678604162159680461914467291840300530057530849048765391711386591646239524912623653881879636239373280423891018672348497668235089863388587925628302755995657524455507255189313690836254779186948667994968324049705821028513185451396213837722826145437693412532098591327667236328125001e-324,
        6755399441055827.499999999999999999999999,
        6755399441055827.5,
        6755399441055827.500000000000000000000001
    };

    ulong[] Right64 = new ulong[ N64 ]
    {
        0x8000000000000000,
        0x8000000000000001,
        0x000ffffffffffffe,
        0x000fffffffffffff,
        0x4338000000000052,
        0x4338000000000053,
        0x7fefffffffffffff,
        0x497ffffffffffffe,
        0x497ffffffffffffe,
        0x497fffffffffffff,
        0x497fffffffffffff,
        0x7feffffffffffffe,
        0x7feffffffffffffe,
        0x7fefffffffffffff,
        0x43405e6cec57761a,
        0x3fe0000000000002,
        0x44997a3c7271b021,
        0x42c0000000000002,
        0x3e0bd5cbaef0fd0c,
        0x433fffffffffffff,
        0x8000000000000001,
        0x4338000000000053,
        0x4338000000000054,
        0x4338000000000054
    };

    // Более сложный тест из https://github.com/Zealint/fp_tests/blob/master/TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp
    const int N64Hard = 9;

    double[] Test64Hard = new double[ N64Hard ]
    {
        2.225073858507201383090232717332404064219215980462331830553327416887204434813918195854283159012511020564067339731035811005152434161553460108856012385377718821130777993532002330479610147442583636071921565046942503734208375250806650616658158948720491179968591639648500635908770118304874799780887753749949451580451605050915399856582470818645113537935804992115981085766051992433352114352390148795699609591288891602992641511063466313393663477586513029371762047325631781485664350872122828637642044846811407613911477062801689853244110024161447421618567166150540154285084716752901903161322778896729707373123334086988983175067838846926092773977972858659654941091369095406136467568702398678315290680984617210924625396728515625e-308,
        2.2250738585072018771558785585789482407880088486837041956131300312119688603996006965297904292212628858639037013670281908017171296072711910355127227413175152199055740043138804567803233377539881639177387328959246074229270113078053813397081653361296447449529789521218979090783852583365901851789618799885150427514782636076021680436220311292700454832073964845713103912225963935608322440623896907276890186717054549275173986589324810401738228328251245795065655738191038008646911615828719989708647293221449796971546706720399791990809160347625980385995424739847678861180095072511543762389603716215171729816011544604359531284325406441938645324905389137795680915804792405099227413854274942620542640408839836919187418172987793340279242767544565229087538682506419718265533447265625e-308,
        2.225073858507202371221524399825492417356801716905076560672932645536733285985283197205297699430014751163740063003020570598281825052988921962169433097257311618680370015095758583081036528065392691763555900744906711111645647364804112062758171723538798309937366264595295182248000398368305570577036006227080633922504922164288936230661591439894977428478987977026639696679140794688312373772389232659678427752122018252042155806801495766953982188063736129641369100312575820243717972293621169304087413797478551780397864281278268544917722045363748655580517781818995617950934297749406849316597964346304638590078974833882923081797242441461636291003104968899481242069589385613709015202152589845793237400783350172912858237869043043055848553508913045817507736501283943653106689453125e-308,
        2.22507385850720163012305563795567615250361241457301801308322872404958664760675944619203679411688695321398552054903200090343478188441232557218436756334761702051817599892294139362996674259828589999483014897143355557856769327930601597818316214242506796246078529588519927249357768832073249247992481686923224716596493432925878395010225097395757951057160073834364573849432419299709217920738991976169431413149717326525502008499797367678374315520581880443916381057236779117517775622749741380425338708447819365553307386742083452616251302946202273010905482006765402020154711200202813970014157525912344017736224427371246815175018974555997865323425588621961151633592416795802960447706494647018477736093430045142168360701364747951396213837722826145437693412532098591327667236328125e-308,
        2.22507385850720163012305563795567615250361241457301801308322872404958664760675944619203679411688695321398552054903200090343478188441232557218436756334761702051817599892294139362996674259828589999483014897143355557856769327930601597818316214242506796246078529588519927249357768832073249247992481686923224716596493432925878395010225097395757951057160073834364573849432419299709217920738991976169431413149717326525502008499797367678374315520581880443916381057236779117517775622749741380425338708447819365553307386742083452616251302946202273010905482006765402020154711200202813970014157525912344017736224427371246815175018974555997865323425588621961151633592416795802960447706494647018477736093430045142168360701364747951396213837722826145437693412532098591327667236328124999e-308,
        2.22507385850720163012305563795567615250361241457301801308322872404958664760675944619203679411688695321398552054903200090343478188441232557218436756334761702051817599892294139362996674259828589999483014897143355557856769327930601597818316214242506796246078529588519927249357768832073249247992481686923224716596493432925878395010225097395757951057160073834364573849432419299709217920738991976169431413149717326525502008499797367678374315520581880443916381057236779117517775622749741380425338708447819365553307386742083452616251302946202273010905482006765402020154711200202813970014157525912344017736224427371246815175018974555997865323425588621961151633592416795802960447706494647018477736093430045142168360701364747951396213837722826145437693412532098591327667236328125001e-308,
        2.22507385850720212418870147920222032907240528279439037814303133837435107319244194686754406432563881851382188218502438069999947733013005649884107791928741341929297200970481951993067993290969042784064731682041565926728632933630474670123316852983422152744517260835859654566319282835244787787799894310779783833699159288594555213714181128458251145584319223079897504395086859412457230891738946169368372321191373658977977723286698840356390251044443035457396733706583981055420456693824658413747607155981176573877626747665912387199931904006317334709003012790188175203447190250028061277777916798391090578584006464715943810511489154282775041174682194133952466682503431306181587829379004205392375072083366693241580002758391118854188641513168478436313080237596295773983001708984374999e-308,
        2.22507385850720212418870147920222032907240528279439037814303133837435107319244194686754406432563881851382188218502438069999947733013005649884107791928741341929297200970481951993067993290969042784064731682041565926728632933630474670123316852983422152744517260835859654566319282835244787787799894310779783833699159288594555213714181128458251145584319223079897504395086859412457230891738946169368372321191373658977977723286698840356390251044443035457396733706583981055420456693824658413747607155981176573877626747665912387199931904006317334709003012790188175203447190250028061277777916798391090578584006464715943810511489154282775041174682194133952466682503431306181587829379004205392375072083366693241580002758391118854188641513168478436313080237596295773983001708984375e-308,
        2.22507385850720212418870147920222032907240528279439037814303133837435107319244194686754406432563881851382188218502438069999947733013005649884107791928741341929297200970481951993067993290969042784064731682041565926728632933630474670123316852983422152744517260835859654566319282835244787787799894310779783833699159288594555213714181128458251145584319223079897504395086859412457230891738946169368372321191373658977977723286698840356390251044443035457396733706583981055420456693824658413747607155981176573877626747665912387199931904006317334709003012790188175203447190250028061277777916798391090578584006464715943810511489154282775041174682194133952466682503431306181587829379004205392375072083366693241580002758391118854188641513168478436313080237596295773983001708984375001e-308
    };

    ulong[] Right64Hard = new ulong[ N64Hard ]
    {
        0x0010000000000000,
        0x0010000000000001,
        0x0010000000000002,
        0x0010000000000000,
        0x0010000000000000,
        0x0010000000000001,
        0x0010000000000001,
        0x0010000000000002,
        0x0010000000000002
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        // Проверка всех чисел одинарной точности в цикле   
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n::: Single precision :::\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < N32; i++)
            test32(Test32[i], Right32[i], i);

        // Проверка всех чисел двойной точности в цикле
        Console.WriteLine("\n::: Double precision :::\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < N64; i++)
            test64(Test64[i], Right64[i], i);

        // Более сложная проверка (TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp)
        Console.WriteLine("\n::: Double precision (TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp) :::\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < N64Hard; i++)
            test64(Test64Hard[i], Right64Hard[i], i);
    }
}
```

---

Обновление: тесты с `long double` перенести на C# не получится, т. к. аналога типа данных `long double` (80 бит с плавающей запятой) в .NET текущей версии [нету](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx).

---

Обновление: добавил тесты из https://github.com/Zealint/fp_tests/blob/master/TestIEEE754ConvertionHard3.cpp

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо, @VladD. В UPD к вопросам, как я обещал, есть более сложные тесты, но я не уверен, что стандарт С# ими не нарушается, там довольно длинные числа (стандарт C++ точно не нарушается).

Comment: @Zealint: К сожалению, в C# не поддерживается `long double`, так что более сложные тесты запустить не смогу.

Comment: Очень жаль. Могу попробовать подумать, что могло бы завалить С#. Сейчас подумаю над double. Есть ли какие-то ограничения на длину числа в стандарте языка?

Comment: @Zealint: Я таких ограничений не помню, но сейчас почитаю стандарт.

Comment: @Zealint: Согласно документации ([C# Language Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), §2.4.4.3), ограничений вроде нет, кроме двух: (1) If the specified literal cannot be represented in the indicated type, a compile-time error occurs. The value of a real literal of type float or double is determined by using the IEEE “round to nearest” mode. (2) in a real literal, decimal digits are always required after the decimal point. For example, 1.3F is a real literal but 1.F is not

Comment: В общем, я добавил в репозиторий файл, оканчивающийся на Hard3. Вы можете взять оттуда только массивы чисел и ответов для double (9 тестов), остальная часть один-в-один такая же. Там меньше 800 знаков, должно хватить. CLang их проходит.

Comment: @Zealint: Сработало! Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Надо же, как бывает, а вот VC++ 2015 это даже не компилирует, хотя по сути продукт одной фирмы.

Comment: @Zealint: Разработчики MSVC связаны по рукам обратной совместимостью, а в C# можно было сделать сразу правильно. Думаю, дело в этом.

Comment: @Zealint, а ведь с VS C++ тоже нет long double. Точнее, компилятор-то съест, но реально там будет 8-байтый double, а не 10-байтный long double. По крайней мере, так в VS2010 было, в более новых не проверял.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так и есть, в силу каких-то причин там отказались от 80-битного числа с плавающей точкой. Но данный продукт в любом случае не работает даже с обычным double. И вряд ли научится в ближайшие 10 тысяч лет.

Answer (score 2):

gcc 4.9.2 вроде проходит. На всех четырёх.
Везде "Right on" и "OK".

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю, можно считать GCC этой версии и выше единственным на данный момент кандидатом на умение работать с плавающей точкой. Странно, а чем занимались разработчики остальных компиляторов С/С++?