# Разделение числа на целую и дробную часть С++

Tags: c++

нужна помощь в разделении:

```
double a = 278654.678 ;  
long int b;  
unsigned short int c;
```

нужно получить:

```
b = 278654;  
c = 678;
```

но если:

```
a = 2.45982;
```

то нужно получить:

```
b = 2;
c = 45982;
```

Проблема именно в выводе нужного количества цифр, что делать?

Comment: Перевести в строку, поделить по точке, перевести обратно в число. Если не перекосит из-за неточности десятичное <=> двоичное, то пофиг, сколько там цифирей.

Comment: Просто интересно, как вы будете отличать случаи 2.5 и 2.005, например... И еще - это ничего, что 2.45982 на самом деле представляется как 2.459820000000000117...?

Comment: Это случаем не проблема XY? Зачем их так разделять?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае ваша задача не может быть решена средствами компиляторов, работающих на основе арифметики с плавающей запятой типа IEEE-754. Одну из причин правильно указали выше в комментарии, число `2.45982` будет сохранено компилятором (ЕСЛИ он правильно работает, что [далеко не факт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512292/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-c-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81)) как `2.459820000000000117523768494720570743083953857421875`. По этой причине, записав такую константу вы УЖЕ внесли ошибку и о точном получении дробной части того, что вы хотели уже речи идти не может.

Во-вторых, вам тоже верно указали в комментарии, как быть с лидирующими нулями в числе, например, `2,005`, вы не можете сохранить в числе типа `int` величину `005`, то есть информация о лидирующих нулях будет утеряна.

В-третьих, в процессе отделения дробной части от целой в десятичном формате будут возникать ошибки, связанные с округлением, по какой причине итог будет вообще непонятным.

Однако есть выход, вернее, псевдо-выход с большой вероятностью ошибки.

Есть функции, которые умеют переводить число в строку, например,

```
int sprintf( char *buffer, const char *format, ... );
```

Вы можете записать в строку `buffer` дробное число с некоторой небольшой точностью, например, так:

```
sprintf (buffer, "%.8lf", a);
```

Далее нужно в этой строке найти точку и получаете слева - целую часть, а справа - дробную. Что с ними делать дальше - дело ваше.

Второй вариант - делать всё вручную. Например, умножать число `a` на `10` до тех пор, пока оно не станет целым, то есть пока не добьётесь условия `a-floor(a) < EPS`, где `EPS` равно некоторой величине, которую можно считать нулём. Скажем `ESP=1e-10`.
Теперь когда вы знаете сколько раз пришлось умножить на `10`, знаете и длину дробной части, а дальше - дело техники. Только следите, чтобы при переводе в целое число вам хватило битов для записи результата без переполнения, а то придётся ещё и это вручную отслеживать.

Но я повторюсь, ТОЧНОГО решения задачи в том виде, в котором вы просите, вы встроенными средствами НЕ получите. Этого можно добиться только ручными костылями, а это уже очень долгий разговор, требующий некоторых не вполне тривиальных знаний.

Вообще, у меня острое подозрения, что вам нужна не эта задача, а что-то другое, просто вы это что-то другое решаете неправильно и приходите в тупик.